# Android studio Gradle project sync completed with errors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have recently started learning android studio and install android studio on linux mint 18 and got stuck at this problem. My build.gradle file contains this code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.justjava"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: `Gradle project sync completed with errors` do you expect anyone to help you fixing errors that he does not know?! Plz provide the error/s and explain what does `this problem` mean!

Comment: use gradlew assemble --info to get more details

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace your `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'`
with newest Dependency like `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`

Comment: It is a good tip, since it is never a good idea to use the + wildcard, but it is not related to the issue.